# How could macOS be POSIX compliant without vi?

Tags: unix, vi

As macOS is POSIX compliant and Unix certified, why does vi redirects to vim?
As I understand, vim is not POSIX compliant.
So how did Apple obtained a Unix certification without having vi installed on their OS?

Comment: Adding to the current answer: *Certified* or de-jure "compliant" doesn't mean that it's actually de-facto *compliant*. To be UNIX™ you need to pass the TET3 testsuite (amongst other things) – think of a big unit-test. If something is not covered, it's "fine" to diverge. Eg. Apple had issues with the extended exit-code for waitid being wrongly bitmasked but still passed. To give credit where credit is due: They fixed that in the next release, iirc.

Comment: Vim runs in compatible mode when it detect that it was run as `vi`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's actually *optional*.

Per the [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)
 in the  *Shells & Utilities* Volume, the `vi` command states:

> This utility shall be provided on systems that both support the User Portability Utilities option and define the POSIX2_CHAR_TERM symbol. On other systems it is optional.

That particular specification is a component of the [Unix 03 product standard](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/xym0.htm) which is what [macOS Catalina](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3653.htm) is certified for.